# Update to gradle 3.2.1 in Android studio 2.3.3 not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got the message from google that I need to update the API level to 28 or above few weeks ago and since then I'm trying to do this and having problems and can't fix my app to build.

I've tried all the manuals, tutorials and advice over the web.

I can't update to the new Android studio version because that is braking my project in all kind of ways and I'm really stuck and soon my app won't work anymore.

I'm not an Android developer, I'm an IOS developer who developed one app that is a nice, free service for many people and want it to stay alive.

This is where I stand right now:

1. I've ran rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
2. Cleaned the wrapper/dist
3. Downloaded gradle 3.2.1 and added it to the VS app content library:

[image]

Changed the gradle version and tried different plugin versions.

[image]

4. This my gradle-wrapper.properties contents:

## Sat Oct 26 13:43:37 IDT 2019

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-all.zip

5. My dependencies in build.gradle for the project:

   buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

   ```
   // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
   // in the individual module build.gradle files
   ```

   }
   }
6. dependencies for the build.gradle for the app:

[image]

** Getting the following when syncing - and I just don't understand what to do anymore **

[image]

*** I've looked and there are no pom and jar files for 3.2.1 in the directory, the error is correct but don't have any idea how to fix that ***

p.s. I've downloaded the gradle 3.2.1 because from what I understand, that is the version that is needed to build the API level 28.

10x

Comment: is it an option to update android studio to the current stable release? 2.3.3 is old

Comment: That is was i said, When i upgrade the Android studio there are many other issues  so im trying to avoid it

Comment: @Erez The longer you try to avoid the newer versions, the number of problems you will encounter is just going to increase. At one point you will have to take out a chunk of time to upgrade. So better to do it now than later. I hope it is something feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i've fixed the issue by updating Android studio to the newest version and fixed all the issues that presented.

This indeed fixed it.

But with that it caused a new problem, for some reason my android key doesn't work anymore so i can't upload the new version to the play store.

This is a huge issue as google support stuff not answering me!

Comment: what is the New Issue..?